# Web API Controller returning Task not always waits for task completion (puppeteer-sharp)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, puppeteer-sharp

I have Web API controller which returns Task which is orginally created in external library service. I return Task in all the chain from serice to controller, but the problem is that when i make the HTTP call to that controller, first time when i have started the API (it`s always takes a bit longer first time) it returns the expected result perfectly, bu when I make the request second time and so on.. it returns some partial result.

When I debug it it always returns the expected correct result. Obvously there is something that is now awaited..

here is the code:

```
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadBinary(string content)
        {
            byte[] recordToDown =  await ExternalLibraryConverter.GetAsync(content);

            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new ByteArrayContent(recordToDown)
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = "Test file"
                };

            // added so Angular can see the Content-Disposition header
            result.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");

            result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

            return result;
        }
```

and the service:

```
        public static async Task<byte[]> GetAsync(string content)
        {

            await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = true,
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);

            using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                await page.SetCacheEnabledAsync(false).ConfigureAwait(false);

                await page.SetContentAsync(content).ConfigureAwait(false);

                await page.AddStyleTagAsync("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,400i,600,700").ConfigureAwait(false);

                // few more styles add

                var result = await page.GetContentAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                PdfOptions pdfOptions = new PdfOptions()
                {
                    PrintBackground = true,
                    MarginOptions = new PuppeteerSharp.Media.MarginOptions {
                        Right = "15mm", Left = "15mm", Top = "20mm", Bottom = "20mm" },
                };
                byte[] streamResult = await page.PdfDataAsync(pdfOptions)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);

                browser.Dispose();

                return streamResult;
            }
        }
```

There are a lot of await in the service with extenral library as you can see. I tried using ConfigureAwait(false) everywhere where await is used, but this didnt help neither.

Comment: What do you mean by "partial result"? I see you're converting a web page into a PDF. Are you getting a partial PDF file that is invalid and you can't even open? Or are you getting a valid PDF file with only part of the web page?

Comment: Have you tested to remove all **.ConfigureAwait(false)** in the GetAsync method?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I`m getting valid PDF with only part of the web page. When I use debugg all data is there. But in nirmal Run, except the first time is always partial data.

Comment: @FredrikStigsson Yes. Same result

Comment: Might be a bug in the external library you are using.

Comment: @FredrikStigsson I agree. If it was a problem with your code, Jackie, I would expect a PDF that wasn't closed off properly and you would get a PDF you can't even open. If you can make a minimal example that reads from a public website, you could post an issue on their GitHub [here](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp/issues).

Comment: By the way, you don't need to call `page.Dispose()` since the `using` will do it for you. That's the entire purpose of [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using).

Answer (score 3):

I think you should not do a .ConfigureAwait on the controller level, look at this article for more information: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html.

ASP.NET team dropped the use of SynchronizationContext, so using it in your controller is pointless.

As the article states, you should still use it on your service level, as you don't know whether or not a UI could plug itself to the service and use it, but on your WEB API, you can drop it.

Comment: You are correct, yes. I will edit the post. However this does not change the attitude.